# MySQL INSERT ...SELECT with SUBQUERY

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I have to do a insert query, inserting data from another table,

condition: if I have a 'codigoTipo' = 'A' ,  the column 'numero' should be the last 'numero' + 1

e.g.:

```
id | codigoTipo   |   numero 
1  |      A       |     1   
2  |      O       |     1   
3  |      A       |     2   
4  |      A       |     3
```

```
   INSERT asociados (id, codigoTipo, numero, cp, direccion, email, fax, movil, nombre, nombreEncargado,  telefono, website, idLocalidad) 
    SELECT p.id, 'A', (MAX(asociados.numero)+1 ) , p.postalcode, p.address, p.mail, p.fax, p.movil, p.name, p.charge_person, p.phone, p.website, p.locality 
    FROM 
partners as p, asociados
```

How can I do that? My code has an error.

Edit: codigoTipo and numero, are a compositePK thats why I need the autoincremental number in column 'numero'

Comment: What is codigoTipo is not 'A', what should the value be?

Comment: codigoTipo can be 'A', 'O' or 'I' .

Comment: If codigoTipo is 'O' or 'I', what should the value of **numero** be?

Comment: codigoTipo and numero are a composite PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the maximum numero.

```
INSERT asociados (id, codigoTipo, numero, cp, direccion,
    email, fax, movil, nombre, nombreEncargado,  telefono, website, idLocalidad) 
SELECT p.id, 'A', dm.MaxNum + 1 , p.postalcode, p.address,
   p.mail, p.fax, p.movil, p.name, p.charge_person,
   p.phone, p.website, p.locality 
FROM partners as p, (SELECT MAX(numero) MaxNum FROM asociados) dm
```

Update: If you want the rows being inserted to increase, use this query:

```
INSERT asociados (id, codigoTipo, numero, cp, direccion,
    email, fax, movil, nombre, nombreEncargado,  telefono, website, idLocalidad) 
SELECT p.id, 'A', @r := @r + 1 , p.postalcode, p.address,
   p.mail, p.fax, p.movil, p.name, p.charge_person,
   p.phone, p.website, p.locality 
FROM partners as p, (SELECT @r := MAX(numero) MaxNum FROM asociados) dm
```

Comment: Won't `dm.MaxNum + 1` have the same value for all rows?

Comment: @ronnis It will, as far as i know the OP wants the same.

Comment: have a error with the updated query : "Duplicate entry 'A-0' for key 2"

Comment: @the-scrum-meister MAX(numero) was returning a NULL, because I don't have files yet, solved with this (SELECT @r := IFNULL(MAX(numero),0). thank you!